# Making a button group act like radiobuttons with Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button, buttongroup

Hopefully can someone help me with this one, I can't figure it out.

I have 3 buttons in Bootstrap with one default active, see http://jsfiddle.net/sbystxp2/, number two has the active state.

So far so good, but now I want the active state changed when I click on one or three and when I do that, the active state of number two must also disappear.

Anyone any idea how to do that with Jquery?

```
$('.checkit .btn').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().find('input').val($(this).data("value"));
});

$('#one').on('click', function () {
    alert('one is clicked');
});

$('#two').on('click', function () {
    alert('two is clicked');
});

$('#three').on('click', function () {
    alert('three is clicked');
});
```

Kind regards,

Arie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    $('.btn').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

and then select `clicked` by

```
   $(".btn.active")
```

Answer (score 5):

Actually you can do this with Bootstrap itself. Here's an example from the docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#buttons-checkbox-radio